# sh script to get rid of block of text on multiple lines

Tags: sed, sh

Maybe this has been asked, but I cant quite seem to find it, but the problem is that I want to get rid of a block of text (or any time it comes up in a file), and replace it with nothing. The example is decoding a certificate and removing bag attributes, in which the blocks of text can vary slightly in between the beginning and end text, but they always start the same and end with the line I want to keep:

e.g.
The file will contain text like the following, and may have several instances when chained certificates are used:

> *Bag Attributes 
>
> localKeyID: xx 00 yy 00 
>
> friendlyName: something.domain.com 
>
> subject=/serialNumber=Coporate Entity/jurisdictionCountryName=US 
>
> /jurisdictionStateOrProvinceName=Washington/businessCategory=Corporate Entity/C=US 
> /ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Bobs Place/OU=Bobs/CN=something.domain.com 
>
> issuer=/C=GB/O=GoDaddy/CN=GoDaddy Certificate*
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

I want to be able to look for this pattern that starts with "Bag Attributes" and ends with the line that contains "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and delete all the lines BEFORE the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" (the italicized text only). When they are chained the previous cert entry ends with ""-----END CERTIFICATE-----", so I don't want to just go back to the beginning of the file or so many lines, I really want to start with the "Bag Attributes" line and end with the line prior to the next "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" string.

I tried the following, but only succeeded in deleting all the contents, and not just the lines I wanted:

> sed -i -ne '/Bag Attributes/ {p; r $CertName.pem' -e ':a; n; /-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/ {p; b}; ba}; p' "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"

This was supposed to take the file "$CertName.pem" and look for everything starting with "Bag Attributes" through the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" line and then just replace it with "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", but that obviously did not work as I was hoping.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` it is easy:

```
awk '
  /-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----/ {pr=0}
  /Bag Attributes/ {pr=1}
  pr==0 {print}
' file
```

With `sed` you can do:

```
 sed 's/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----/\r/' file |
    sed -rz 's/Bag Attributes[^\r]*\r/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work via the following, but now have one more issue.

Working line to get rid of the bag attributes throughout:

> sed -ne '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/p' $CertName.pem > $CertName.tmp1

Now I also have to remove one of the entries in the certificate chain, so how do I reverse the lines above and look for the string of two lines and ends with two lines, then trim out that block of information?:

e.g. look for pattern

-----Begin Certificate-----

abxdrfg12765

through

oiyrntlklkdn

-----End Certificate-----

like in this example below to find and delete the italicized text:

> -----Begin Certificate-----
>
> acbdef123456
>
> mlkhdsftonnl
>
> ljhfnodvlndv
>
> qpiuekjnxvsn
>
> lmnopqr43210
>
> -----End Certificate-----
>
> *-----Begin Certificate-----
>
> abxdrfg12765
>
> mlkhdsftonnl
>
> ljhfnodvlndv
>
> qpiuekjnxvsn
>
> oiyrntlklkdn
>
> -----End Certificate-----*
>
> -----Begin Certificate-----
>
> xyzabc543211
>
> mlkhdsftonnl
>
> ljhfnodvlndv
>
> qpiuekjnxvsn
>
> lmnopqr43210
>
> -----End Certificate-----

The two blocks of text above and below the italicized text have different patterns, but the first is always unpredictable, and the second and third blocks of text may be swapped, so again I cant find *n* lines down or up and remove those, so again I have to look for the multi-line pattern and remove that block of text, but since SED doesn't do great at multi-line text, how would I do this type of parsing and deletion?

Any suggestions for problem 2?